# cross database query only works one way MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am attempting to insert data about index usage into a control database of sorts..  The query I am using is below..  the issue I have is that when I execute the query from the control database (lets call it A) it returns 0 results, but if I execute it from the source database (lets call that B) it runs just fine..
why?

This behavior is being seen on both  SQL Server 2012 DEV and SQL Server 2008 EE.

Example 1 returns zero results:

```
USE A;

INSERT INTO A.dbo.UnusedIndexes
SELECT 
    DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
    , SCHEMA_NAME(o.Schema_ID) AS SchemaName
    , OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) AS TableName
    , ix.name AS IndexName
    ,((SUM(ps.used_page_count)over(partition by ix.index_id))*8)/1024 AS [IndexSizeMB]
    , ix_usage_stats.user_updates
    , ix_usage_stats.user_seeks + ix_usage_stats.user_scans + ix_usage_stats.user_lookups
                            AS [User_SeeksScansLookups]
    , ix_usage_stats.system_updates                         
    , ix_usage_stats.system_seeks + ix_usage_stats.system_scans + ix_usage_stats.system_lookups
                            AS [System_SeeksScansLookups]
    , NULL as [Drop_Statement]
    , NULL as [Create_statement]
    ,getdate() as [date_added]
    
    
FROM B.sys.indexes ix
Left join B.sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ix_usage_stats
 ON ix_usage_stats.object_id = ix.object_id
    AND ix_usage_stats.index_id = ix.index_id
INNER JOIN B.sys.objects o ON ix.object_id = o.object_id
JOIN B.sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps ON ps.object_id = ix.object_id AND ix.index_id = ps.index_id
WHERE 
    ix.name IS NOT NULL -- exclude heaps
    AND ix.type <> 1 -- exclude the clustered indexes
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- exclude system objects
    AND o.type NOT IN('F', 'UQ') -- exclude the foreign keys and unique contraints
    AND SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) not in ('dbo','stats', 'reporting') 
    AND (ix_usage_stats.user_seeks = 0 or ix_usage_stats.user_seeks is NULL)
    AND (ix_usage_stats.user_scans = 0 or ix_usage_stats.user_scans is null)
    AND (ix_usage_stats.user_lookups = 0 or ix_usage_stats.user_lookups is null)
```

Example 2 returns the expected results, populating A.dbo.UnusedIndexes:

```
USE B;
INSERT INTO A.dbo.UnusedIndexes
SELECT 
    DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
    , SCHEMA_NAME(o.Schema_ID) AS SchemaName
    , OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) AS TableName
    , ix.name AS IndexName
    ,((SUM(ps.used_page_count)over(partition by ix.index_id))*8)/1024 AS [IndexSizeMB]
    , ix_usage_stats.user_updates
    , ix_usage_stats.user_seeks + ix_usage_stats.user_scans + ix_usage_stats.user_lookups
                            AS [User_SeeksScansLookups]
    , ix_usage_stats.system_updates                         
    , ix_usage_stats.system_seeks + ix_usage_stats.system_scans + ix_usage_stats.system_lookups
                            AS [System_SeeksScansLookups]
    , NULL as [Drop_Statement]
    , NULL as [Create_statement]
    ,getdate() as [date_added]
    
    
FROM B.sys.indexes ix
Left join B.sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ix_usage_stats
 ON ix_usage_stats.object_id = ix.object_id
    AND ix_usage_stats.index_id = ix.index_id
INNER JOIN B.sys.objects o ON ix.object_id = o.object_id
JOIN B.sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps ON ps.object_id = ix.object_id AND ix.index_id = ps.index_id
WHERE 
    ix.name IS NOT NULL -- exclude heaps
    AND ix.type <> 1 -- exclude the clustered indexes
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- exclude system objects
    AND o.type NOT IN('F', 'UQ') -- exclude the foreign keys and unique contraints
    AND SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) not in ('dbo','stats', 'reporting') 
    AND (ix_usage_stats.user_seeks = 0 or ix_usage_stats.user_seeks is NULL)
    AND (ix_usage_stats.user_scans = 0 or ix_usage_stats.user_scans is null)
    AND (ix_usage_stats.user_lookups = 0 or ix_usage_stats.user_lookups is null)
```

This works all day long:

```
USE A;
Select * from B.sys.indexes
```

Any help would be great - and unfortunately I am unable to execute this from database B, so the easy solution won't work.

---

#### Solved

Figured it out. the DB_NAME() was the issue. removing that and setting it to 'B' as databasename fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you understand that `DB_NAME()` will return name of your current context database not the database you are specifying in `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses. In your first example you will return `A` even thought you are getting data from `B`

Comment: have you tried to remove your `INSERT INTO A.dbo.UnusedIndexes` statement and just verify that both queries return same results?

Comment: I do understand that - but even with DB_NAME() in the query it returns 0 rows when executed from A

Comment: Yes - I have tried doing selects - and that wasn't working either..  but I just figured it out - thanks to your comment about DB_NAME().. setting that to a constant fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you have some sort of constrain on your table that verified database?

Comment: so you figured it out yourself, fine. but please don't post the answer as an edit, post it as an answer and mark it the accepted answer. that way people will see, that your question has an answer and this will make the question more interesting/worth reading for people who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sp_executesql from the target database:

```
USE A;

INSERT INTO A.dbo.UnusedIndexes
EXEC B.sys.sp_executesql N'
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(o.Schema_ID) AS SchemaName
    ,OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) AS TableName
    ,ix.NAME AS IndexName
    ,((SUM(ps.used_page_count) OVER (PARTITION BY ix.index_id)) * 8) / 1024 AS [IndexSizeMB]
    ,ix_usage_stats.user_updates
    ,ix_usage_stats.user_seeks + ix_usage_stats.user_scans + ix_usage_stats.user_lookups AS [User_SeeksScansLookups]
    ,ix_usage_stats.system_updates
    ,ix_usage_stats.system_seeks + ix_usage_stats.system_scans + ix_usage_stats.system_lookups AS [System_SeeksScansLookups]
    ,NULL AS [Drop_Statement]
    ,NULL AS [Create_statement]
    ,getdate() AS [date_added]
FROM sys.indexes ix
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ix_usage_stats
    ON ix_usage_stats.object_id = ix.object_id
        AND ix_usage_stats.index_id = ix.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
    ON ix.object_id = o.object_id
JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
    ON ps.object_id = ix.object_id
        AND ix.index_id = ps.index_id
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND ix.name IS NOT NULL -- exclude heaps
    AND ix.type <> 1 -- exclude the clustered indexes
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- exclude system objects
    AND o.type NOT IN(''F'', ''UQ'') -- exclude the foreign keys and unique contraints
    AND SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) not in (''dbo'',''stats'', ''reporting'') 
    AND (
        ix_usage_stats.user_seeks = 0
        OR ix_usage_stats.user_seeks IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        ix_usage_stats.user_scans = 0
        OR ix_usage_stats.user_scans IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        ix_usage_stats.user_lookups = 0
        OR ix_usage_stats.user_lookups IS NULL
        )
'
```

Comment: BTW, I blogged about a better method than dynamic SQL here: http://spaghettidba.com/2013/04/22/a-viable-alternative-to-dynamic-sql-in-administration-scripts/